# Cannot connect to VM Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking if I change the release version of spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I don't know why my tests is not running when I change the spring version to 1.5.2.Release.

When I try to run a single test, without no further configuration, I got "Problem ocurred: Cannot connect to VM Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking"

But if I turn back to the previous version of Spring Boot (1.4.5.Release), my test runs.

I'm using Eclipse Neon.3, java 1.8.0_121 and I've tried to modify configuration based on related links that I've searched, including disabling firewall.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
...

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <dcm4che.version>2.0.29</dcm4che.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- json impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- libs dcm4che -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-net</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-tool-dcmqr</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-tool-dcmwado</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-tool-dcmsnd</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-tool-jpg2dcm</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
        <artifactId>dcm4che-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>${dcm4che.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>servidorIntelicon</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dcm4che</id>
        <name>dcm4che Repository</name>
        <url>http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Maven,

Consider removing the *maven-shade-plugin* dependency from the pom.xml (in case you have).

Surprisingly, it worked for me.

Comment: I'm not using maven-shade-plugin. I updated the question description with my pom.xml. Tks!!

Comment: How I solved my issue.

1) Created a brand new project with a single class to ensure that Eclipse debugging properly in Ecplise.

2) Went back to "buggy" project and started removing libs one by one. It's hard to says what is actually causing the problem but certainly it comes from a lib conflict. The error message isn't much helpful.

Best luck